# Generating SSL cert using certbot - multiple DNS entries

Tags: dns, certbot

I currently have 2 DNS A records for main domain pointing to the different IP addresses. This is creating problems when I try to use *certbot* to generate Let's Encrypt's SSL certificate for my domain, because it seems that when doing http-01 validation to prove that I own the domain, it takes just the first host that is resolved and tries to do the validation agains it, but as this first isn't currently online, it cannot validate it.

Is it any way to tell certbot to check the other IP, because it seems that it's just checking the first one.

I guess that it checks the wrong IP because I see this as output: "Invalid response from http://atarichain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/lg3F-y0QuyxzpVicLybJ-UWkW6Cm01E3Ccc7-LP1nrg [*x.x.x.x*]", x.x.x.x being the IP that is not currently working. When I check nslookup I get both IP's (the one that is working and that I want to be used, and the other one that isn't which is the one that certbot tries to contact).

I am aware that deleting the entry might help, but since I'm not personally in control over that nameserver it's not that easy for me to change it.

Comment: Remove the DNS A entry. If it's not online it's no use anyway and your users might get random error messages. Even if you do manage to get a cert that way you might not have one that works across both servers if the second server comes online.

Comment: Browsers actually check for other DNS records if the first one is down, so in browser users always get the right website. I told my college to remove the DNS record for the non-working IP. However, as I just found out, DNS entries sometimes stay on DNS servers for as long as their TTL value is set. So, that might take a while. That's why I'm trying to force certbot to look trough all DNS records not just the first one